# NeDB + Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, nedb

How can I get a datastore with NeDB using typescrip classes syntax?

```
namespace NamespaceName {

"use strict";

export class Persistence {

    private attrs: Type;

    public static $inject: Array<string> = [];

    constructor(
    ) {
        this.attr1 = "";
    }

    // Public Methods
    public method1() {
        ...
    }

    // Private Methods
    private method1() {
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

Where should I create and instantiate my datastore?

Answer (score 1):

I was spinning my wheels on this myself for a while and I was able to do get the database to generate with the following:

```
import NeDB = require('nedb');
//test class
class duck{
    body: string;
    constructor(body: string)
    {
       this.body = body;
    }
}

//method from where I init my database.
testdb() {
    var db:any = new NeDB("./file.db");
    var obj:duck= new duck("A normal duck body");
    db.loadDatabase();
    db.insert(obj);
}
```

Notes:

- I do have the @typings installed for NeDB see [NeDB
  Typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/types-2.0/nedb)
- If you look at the above link they provide the tests they used to verify the typings.